# Celery: form has no len()

Tags: python, django, celery

I have updated my python versions and celery versions, and now it is not possible to create a task from a form submit:

- Python==3.4.
- Django==1.10.3
- celery==4.0.0

My view:

```
class SignupBase(FormView):

    def get_form_class(self, **kwargs):        
        return SignupFormBase


    def form_valid(self, form): 

        user = User(username=generate_random_username())
        user.save()

        signuptask = signup_user.delay(username=user.username,form=form)
```

The traceback when submitting:

```
Traceback:

File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py” in inner

39.             response = get_response(request)
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py” in _legacy_get_response

249.             response = self._get_response(request)
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py” in _get_response

187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py” in _get_response

185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py” in view

68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py” in _wrapped_view_func

57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File “./apps/signup/views.py” in dispatch

203.         return super(SignupBase, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py” in dispatch

88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/views/generic/edit.py” in post

183.             return self.form_valid(form)
File “./apps/signup/views.py” in form_valid

448.         signuptask = signup_user_locally.delay(username=user.username, form=form)
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/task.py” in delay

413.         return self.apply_async(args, kwargs)
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/task.py” in apply_async

536.             **options
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/base.py” in send_task

709.             root_id, parent_id, shadow, chain,
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/amqp.py” in as_task_v2

335.             kwargsrepr = saferepr(kwargs, self.kwargsrepr_maxsize)
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/utils/saferepr.py” in saferepr

74.         o, maxlen=maxlen, maxlevels=maxlevels, seen=seen
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/utils/saferepr.py” in _saferepr

104.     for token, it in reprstream(stack, seen=seen, maxlevels=maxlevels):
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/utils/saferepr.py” in reprstream

155.         for val in it:
File “/home/USER/Env/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/utils/saferepr.py” in _chainlist

91.     size = len(it)
Exception Type: TypeError at /signup/ Exception Value: object of type ‘SignupFormBase’ has no len() Request information: USER: AnonymousUser

GET: No GET data

POST: last_name = ‘Testing’ mobilephone = ‘99999999’ csrfmiddlewaretoken = ‘ShNfv74MEpYdvtbsGcC5lxGIsuuHVz73DNrHqDjsjKtFoDNW4po50cdLF2OXfrJr’ email = ‘testing@test.com’ first_name = ‘Test’
```

Is there something new I Celery that I have missed? Other tasks running with celery beat is working fine, just this one task is not.

Comment: add a `__len__` method to that form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class SignupFormBaseWithLen(SignupFormBase):
    def __len__(self):
        return 10 #here you have to set which len you should pass
```

This method is to check size of arguments you are passing to celery task

Then

```
class SignupBase(FormView):

    def get_form_class(self, **kwargs):        
        return SignupFormBaseWithLen
```

Comment: This is probably a stupid question, but why should the __len__ function return 10? Is there any logic there?

Comment: No i put a random number. This method is to check size of arguments you are passing to celery task.  Since you are passing a form instance i dont know how you get len. Generally people not recommending instances as arguments to celery.